# VB.NET Copy file to network share - The network path was not found

Tags: vb.net, networking, copy

I can successfully copy the file but only as long as the network mapped path is active. It randomly goes inactive. I have 3 users testing right now - 1 user has no issues, 1 had no issues until like halfway through the day and 1 user it failed on first try.

Is there some way to ping the network share until its connected, THEN do the copy? I haven't attempted any code just yet, I'm honestly not sure where to even look. All google results don't really fit the bill.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not gonna post this as answer but if I'm in that situation I'm gonna use a _TryCatch_ and check the message if it is containing the error same to the error it was throwing when the network path is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it fails because it doesn't connect in time (you make the request to the file, Windows does it's stuff slowly to re-connect, then you get a 'Network path was not found' because it timed out).

If this were the case (and it were acceptable to you), you could try/catch it and try again a few times (though hacky, this might work).  You can (and maybe should) put in a check first that see's if the network drive is available (You can use System.IO.Directory to see if the remote directory exists).

(Edited) - Here is the example to try it a few times:

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    ' Loop a few times
    While counter < 3
        Try
            System.IO.File.Copy("c:\test.txt", "c:\test1.txt")
            Exit While
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' You can pause here for a specified amount, you can report
            ' the exception, you can do nothing
        End Try

        counter += 1
    End While
```

Comment: if definitely exists and i think you are correct about windows timing out. to try/catch a few times should be ok, just not sure how to implement it. any pointers?

Comment: Yes.  Give me a few minutes and I'll write something up.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example.  That will try 3 times and will exit the while if it succeeds.

Comment: wow i feel like a real Alfred Einstein. thank you! like you said, its a tad hacky but should be reasonable for my needs, its a simple little application for now anyway.

Comment: Somtimes hacky gets the job done fine and in the end that's the important thing (IMO).  ;-)  Glad it helped.  After you try it out (and if it works for you) feel free to select this as the answer. ;-)

Comment: thats the plan, development is crawling though since i have to code at home, test at work. real pain.

Comment: marked as the answer, thanks again. just gotta tweak it, 3 wasn't enough lol

Comment: Another option is you could also put a statement in that pauses the process for X amount of seconds.  On error, pause 15 seconds, try again.  Whatever gets the job done though, glad it helped! :)